# BibTeX Icon in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex

I'm new to LaTeX. So how can I type the BibTeX icon in LaTeX3?

Desired effect:

[image]

Comment: Try the `hologo` package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're ok with using a package that provides lots of canonical tex-related logos, do look into using the macros provided by the [hvlogos](https://ctan.org/pkg/hvlogos) package.

[image]

Observe that the design of the logo you posted in your screenshot isn't quite canonical; to be canonical, the letter "E" should touch both "T" and "X". This requirement is not unique to the "BibTeX" logo. Indeed, even the classic (plain) TeX logo has the letter "E" touching both "T" and "X".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hvlogos}
\begin{document}
\TeX

\BibTeX
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, the "hv" in "hvlogos" are the initials of the package's author: Herbert Voss.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes things much simpler!